# What does "make somebody" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This sentence is from a story I'm reading. It's from a child's point of view and she's talking about a cat.

> He got big and kind of snobby, and he didn't want to sit in my lap anymore. He would, for a second, if I hoisted him up and **made him**, but once I got settled, he'd wiggle, jump off my lap and prowl around the hallway instead.

What does *made him* mean?

Comment: Make sb do = force sb to do (more or less).

Comment: *He got big and kind of snobby, and he didn't want to sit in my lap anymore. He would, for a second, if I hoisted him up and made him.* -> It means 'he would sit in my lap if I hoisted him up and made him [caused him to sit]. 'Make' in this case is called 'causative verb'.

Comment: To combine comments: If I picked up the cat and forced the cat to sit in my lap.